# show and hide is not happening properly in html through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I did `.toggle()` functionality in jquery on the content. But when i click on read more button the text link disappears and first paragraph becomes invisible.

Here is the jQuery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('article p').hide();
    $('article p').eq(0).show();
    $('p.read-more').show();
    $('p.read-more').click(function(){
        $('article p').show('slow');
        $('article').css('background', '#f5f5f5').show('slow');
        $(this).text('Read Less');
        return false;
        });
    })
```

HTML Code

```
<article class="content">
<p>Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 
</p>

<p>Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 
</p>

<p>Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 
</p>
<p>Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 Dummy Text 1 
</p>
<p class="read-more">Read More</p>
</article>
```

Comment: We'll need some markup to know where the p is in relation to the anchor.

Comment: Please, post your HTML or a jsFiddle.

Comment: See my update. I used your HTML and added your colour change and removed the needless show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion which hides the other Ps from the start. I changed the Read more to a link to get the hand cursor and gave it an ID, if you have many sets, you will need to use the class and closest to find the parent whose content you want to expand

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hjuFf/)

```
 $(function() {
    $("#more").on("click",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".content p:gt(0)").slideToggle("slow",function() {
        var visible = $(".content p:gt(0)").is(':visible');
        $("#more").text(visible ? 'Read less' : 'Read more');
        $('.content').css('background', visible ?'#f5f5f5' : '#fff');  
      });   
   });
});
```

using CSS like this:

```
.content p{
    display:none;
}
.content p:first-child { /* Or nth-child(n+3) if you want more than one */
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this is what you mean:

```
$('p:gt(0)').hide();
$('a.more').click(function () {
    $('p:gt(0)').show('slow');
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/